# Remove row from tibble containing empty string in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Pretty basic question that has me confused. How do I remove rows from a tibble that contain empty character strings?

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  data = c(
    "1 1 2 2 3, 3 4 5 6 7",
    "1 1 3 3, 2 3 4 5",
    ", ",
    "1 1, 2 3"
  ),
  num = c(2, 3, 1, 4)
)


dfTest <- df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  setNames(c("data", "num")) %>%
  separate(data, c("col1", "col2"), ", ")

> dfTest
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  col1        col2          num
  <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>
1 "1 1 2 2 3" "3 4 5 6 7"     2
2 "1 1 3 3"   "2 3 4 5"       3
3 ""          ""              1
4 "1 1"       "2 3"           4
```

Taking a look at `dfTest` we can see that row 3 contains empty character strings. I'm looking for a way to remove these types of rows from a tibble?

Comment: probably a good idea to convert blanks to NA? maybe by doing dfTest %>% mutate_all(na_if,"")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tidyverse solution:

```
dfTest <- dfTest %>% 
  filter(. != "")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  col1      col2        num
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 7     2
2 1 1 3 3   2 3 4 5       3
3 1 1       2 3           4
```

Answer (score 2):

From your question it is not quite clear if you want the row removed only when both strings are empty, or when either of them is.

I changed a bit your example to point at the difference, and detail an approach that allows to select the columns to be checked as well as to clarify if you want all of them or any of them to be empty for them to be removed.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  data = c(
    "1 1 2 2 3, 3 4 5 6 7",
    "1 1 3 3, ",
    ", ",
    "1 1, 2 3"
  ),
  num = c(2, 3, 1, 4)
)


dfTest <- df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  setNames(c("data", "num")) %>%
  separate(data, c("col1", "col2"), ", ") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(!Reduce(f = `|`, x = c_across(col1:col2)=="")) %>%  
  ungroup()
dfTest
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   col1      col2        num
#>   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 7     2
#> 2 1 1       2 3           4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try using `base` R,

```
dfTest[!dfTest$col1 == "", ]
  col1      col2        num
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 7     2
2 1 1 3 3   2 3 4 5       3
3 1 1       2 3           4
```